# JavaScript Object Syntax error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assemble an object with some form data, but I'm pretty sure I'm messing up the syntax - here's a snippet

```
$Device1.u_data.create.nodes.[$('#device-1-ip-1').val()] = {"enabled": true};
$Device1.u_data.create.nodes.[$('#device-1-ip-2').val()] = {"enabled": true};
$Device1.u_data.create.nodes.[$('#device-1-ip-3').val()] = {"enabled": true};
$Device1.u_data.create.nodes.[$('#device-1-ip-4').val()] = {"enabled": true};
```

I think I must be messing something up with the piece that I'm trying to pull from the form. The error I'm seeing in the console is "SyntaxError: missing name after . operator"

Anything obvious that I'm missing? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need `nodes.[]` you just need `nodes[]`

Comment: This can and probably should be refactored into something like `['#device-1-ip-1', '#device-1-ip-2', '#device-1-ip-3', '#device-1-ip-4;'].forEach(function(sel) { $Device1.u_data.create_nodes[$(sel).val()] = {enabled: true}; });`. That is unless you enjoy lots of extra typing and opportunities for mistakes and extra work when you add the 5th element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use square bracket notation to access items in `.nodes`, but you have a dot between "nodes" and the open square bracket.

On all lines you should have something like:

```
$Device1.u_data.create.nodes[$('#device-1-ip-1').val()] = {"enabled": true};
```

Notice I do not have a dot after "nodes"

Answer (score 0):

Syntax issue, you don't need `nodes.[]` you just need `nodes[]`.